# Unity: Reduce size of Render Texture before executing Texture2D.ReadPixels

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a code where I basically have to take a low quality screenshot about every 30 milliseconds. The script is attached to a camara.

What I want to do is reduce the render texture size. The way the code is right now changing either W or H basically gets me a SECTION of of all that is being seen by the camara instead of a reduced size version. So my question is how can I resized or downsample what is read into the screenshot (Texture2D) but that it still is a representation of the entire screen.

```
public class CameraRenderToImage : MonoBehaviour
{

    private  RemoteRenderServer rrs;

    void Start(){
        TimeStamp.SetStart();
        Camera.onPostRender += OnPostRenderCallback;

    }
    
    void OnPostRenderCallback(Camera cam){

        if (TimeStamp.HasMoreThanThisEllapsed(30)){
           TimeStamp.SetStart();

           int W = Screen.width;
           int H = Screen.height;        

           Texture2D screenshot = new Texture2D(W,H, TextureFormat.RGB24, false); 
   
           screenshot.ReadPixels( new Rect(0, 0, W,H), 0, 0);
   
           byte[] bytes = screenshot.EncodeToPNG();
           System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("check_me_out.png", bytes);
           TimeStamp.Tok("Encode to PNG and Save");
   
        }

    }

    // Remove the onPostRender callback
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        Camera.onPostRender -= OnPostRenderCallback;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to resize your render texture from script you can refer to the next code snippet

```
 void Resize(RenderTexture renderTexture, int width, int height) {
      if (renderTexture) {
         renderTexture.Release();
         renderTexture.width = width;
         renderTexture.height = height; 
     }
```

}

To make it possible to resize the render texture you first need to make sure it is released.

To get Texture2d:

```
private Texture2D ToCompressedTexture(ref RenderTexture renderTexture)
    {
        var texture = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        var previousTarget = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        RenderTexture.active = previousTarget;
        texture.Compress(false);
        texture.Apply(false, true);

        renderTexture.Release();
        renderTexture = null;

        return texture;
    }
```

Comment: This will actually help me out. But how do I get it into Texture2D? I think I will fix my question to simplify it and better reflect what I want. Thank you, though

Comment: @aarelovich I have updated the answer regarding your question.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered the trick was to create a new render textrue of lower resoltuion and use blitz to copy the active render texture to the new render texture set the new render texture as active adn THEN do the screenshot. What I'm not sure, in your code, why do you Compress and Apply?

Comment: @aarelovich as stated in Unity docs: Compressed textures use less graphics memory and are faster to render